# cls error when creating reports in asp.net c#

Tags: c#

I have a asp.net c# database using linq that works great. I have the add new and edit options, but now need to create a report. When using report viewer I get field in dataset must be cls compilant identifiers.

what this error means and how to keep working on my report.

Comment: because it starts with an undescore?

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please reword your question and use correct punctuation and grammar. Then your question will be "English Compliant", it makes it easier for third parties to read and understand. There is an ironic metaphor there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

CLS Compliant means that your code is written in such a way to [adhere to "rules and restrictions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the specification; without seeing your identifier name it's hard to say exactly what is wrong with it, but there is something wrong with your naming conventions such that at least one of your identifiers does not comply to recommendations.

Code does need to be compliant by definition, but other apps are free to penalise your for it and extends the robustness of your code for any given CLR.